# Is there a closed-form for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k!)^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, factorial, closed-form

As the title says, I'm wondering whether there is any known closed-from for the following series:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k!)^2}$$

Trying on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B100%7D+1%2F%28k!%29%5E2), I get the value $2.279585302336067267437204440811533353...$ and the continued fraction begins like this $[2; 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 7, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7, 8, 1, 1, 21, 1, 16, 2, 1, 8, 1, 1, 8, ...]$

If you have any reference which focuses on this number, I would also be interested. I found nothing so far!

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you'd used infinity for the upper limit instead of truncating the series, Wolfram|Alpha would have told you that this is $I_0(2)$.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was just trying… !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you might be interested in looking at the [Modified Bessel](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) function. Hence you sum is just

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k!)^2} = I_0(2)$$

I don't think it simplifies further.